# Proof about Dedekind Theorem

Tags: analysis

Following two pics are proof regarding Dedekind Theorem

[image: part I]

[image: part II]

My question is: after prove there is a rational number r greater than $\beta$, we arrived at contradiction, why?

Comment: Actually this book is written by a famous Russian author G. M. Fikhtengol'ts, and Lemma 1 is "For any pair of real numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, where $\alpha$ > $\beta$, there can always be found a real, and even in particular a rational, number r which lies between them, i.e. $\alpha$ > r > $\beta$ (and, consequently, an infinite set of such rational numbers)."

Comment: Yes, since $\beta$ is the greatest number in class A, the contradiction is $\beta$ is NOT the greatest number in class A, we must prove that this contradiction is impossible

Comment: What confused me is that why when we find a rational number r which is in lower class A and greater than $\beta$, then we arrive at the contradiction